# Synology SSH key auth only or, failing that, different SSH password to file share access

Tags: nas, synology-diskstation

I would like to enable SSH key only access (no password logins enabled) for shell accounts on my Synology NAS (DSM 6.2.4-25556 Update 5) to prevent brute forcing attempts.

Alternatively, is it possible to set a different, much stronger, password for the system account and an easier one for Windows file share account of the same name? I.e. for user "example" put a strong password in `/etc/shadow` while the Samba DB uses something easier for casual file sharing access. This is what I used to do on a manually managed server.

Comment: Can you provide the OpenSSH daemon configuration file. You can have as many user accounts as you want, if you disable password authentication, there isn’t an remote attack vector.

Comment: The OpenSSH daemon configuration is managed by Synology DSM and any manual modifications I make will be overwritten by the DSM whenever there is a system update. I was wondering if there is a "front door" approach via the DSM user interface I can use to make these changes.